# Ubuntu 18.04 - logged out after resuming from suspend or even turn the screen off

Tags: nvidia, xorg, suspend, logout

I tried Ubuntu 18.04, Budgie, and both have the same probelm when using nvidia dirver 390 & 396. When resume from suspend the system logout and every program I was working on is closed.

It seems that nvidia driver is not supporting any change I make on xorg.

When switch back to nouveau, the system works normally, and suspend resume is not logging out.

I have almost every solution on the web, including nvidia forum and SE, none of them works.

**UPDATE:**
I reset recursively `org.gnome` using `dconf-editor` and now it works probably till now, it seems to be a gnome-shell problem

**NEW**

> This problem is not a swap error, since I tried to turnoff the swap, in addition, I read the journal output, I is related to gnome-shell dealing with nvidia leads to kill the session when turning on the screen, or waking from sleep.
>
> note: I know this question may be duplicated but for some reason I can't post any answer or put any comment.
>
> Please Please If you realy know the answer share it otherwise don't comment any off topic comment

Comment: There is a known issue, which can seem to happen a bit randomly, and has a workaround you can try.  See [Ubuntu 18.04 - logged out after resuming from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044707/ubuntu-18-04-logged-out-after-resuming-from-suspend) , which was listed at the bottom of the Related list in the right-hand sidebar :)

Comment: @sourcejedi it is not a swap error, I on of the attempts to solve the problem was when swap was disabled

Comment: that bug can occur without swap. it's more usually in the *code* segment, which can always be paged out to disk. "Read-error on swap device" is not an essential part of the bug. I made sure to note in my answer, that "Read-error on swap device" message only occurs in a minority of occasions.  I wrote a more customized answer on your question, but it was deleted since I'd effectively posted the same answer multiple times. There are two possible solutions in the answer which I commend to you. I really hope the accepted update will get released for Ubuntu within the next few weeks though.

Comment: For me, open source driver nouveau always worked more perfect then stable version nvidia driver. Both for work and gaming.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem plague me ... and a fix after many attempts was to re-install Ubuntu 18.04, and now it is working perfectly. I am also using Nvidia's "tested" Driver, as Nvidia was the culprit before.

Perhaps it was the "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers" ppa which installed "Extra" Stuff from the PPA and/or the 396 driver itself which screwed up my laptop's hibernating ability.

Either way it works flawlessly at this time of writing with the NVidia's 390 tested driver.

It is/was definitely related to the NVidia driver as before switching to the Nouveau driver also worked, but I sure did not like that option.

Comment: I also experienced the same issue. For some reason with one of the updates my settings changed and i started to use the nouveau driver. Suspending was not successful, i switched back to the tested driver, now everything works just fine. Thanks for your help!